# Perl - Matching with dont care conditions and reading csv files

Tags: perl, csv, pattern-matching

I posted a question regarding don't care symbol (X) in Perl before. I now have a working code, but this does not work where reading files.

Let's say I have a 50-bit binary input and database. If the input is matched with data in database, I would return a pre-defined value.

Let's say the data in the database is 11001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101 .

If the input is 11XX11001000101101111101101010010000101101011111X1, I would like to say it is a matched case because X can be 1 or 0. I know a way to split 50 bits in 50 1-bit and make an exception, but I would prefer to handle 50-bit together.

In my code (dontcare.pl), the first part is working with internally defined input and database. However, I would like to read an input file (input_text.txt) and an database file (database.txt) that includes other information and do the same thing.

dontcare.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

####### 1st part, Internal string input and database
my $input = '11XX11001000101101111101101010010000101101011111X1';
( my $mask = $input ) =~ tr/X01/\x00\xFF\xFF/;
( my $targ = $input ) =~ tr/X/\x00/;

for my $num_bin (qw(
   11001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101
   10101100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101
)) {
   if (($num_bin & $mask) eq $targ) {
      print "$num_bin matches\n";
   } else {
      print "$num_bin doesn't match\n";      
   }
}


####### 2nd part, Reading input and database files 
        print " Reading files\n";      
##### Read input
my @Dinput=do{
    open my $Dfh,"<","input_test.txt" or die("Cannot open an input file $!");
    <$Dfh>;
};

##### Read database
open(CSV,'database.txt')||die("Cannot open db file $!");
my @Ddb;

while(<CSV>){
    my @row=split(/\t/,$_);
    push(@Ddb,\@row);
}
close CSV || die $!;


for (my $n=0; $n < (scalar @Dinput); $n +=1) {

for (my $i=0; $i < (scalar @Ddb); $i +=2) {
    (my $Dmask = $Dinput[$n]) =~ tr/X01/\x00\xFF\xFF/;
    (my $Dtarg = $Dinput[$n]) =~ tr/X/\x00/;

    if (( $Ddb[$i][1] & $Dmask) eq $Dtarg) {
        print "$Ddb[$i][1] matched\n";
    } else {
        print "$Ddb[$i][1] didn't match\n";      
    }
}

}
```

input_test.txt : (an input file containing two inputs)

```
11XX11001000101101111101101010010000101101011111X1
1000011000111101001011110111001100100101111000010X
```

database.txt : (a database file. It has 50-bit binary in the second column.Other information are also in the file)

```
0.1 11001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101  rml_irf_old_e_cwp_e[1]  rml_irf_new_e_cwp_e[1]  rml_irf_swap_even_e rml_irf_old_e_cwp_e[0]  rml_irf_new_e_cwp_e[0]  rml_irf_swap_odd_e
0.1 11101100110010011011001101100111001001100000010011  3.923510310023e-06  3.19470818154393e-08    7.05437377900141e-10    7.05437377900141e-10    4.89200539851702e-17    5.01433479478681e-19
0.1 10000110001111010010111101110011001001011110000100  rml_irf_new_e_cwp_e[1]  rml_irf_new_e_cwp_e[0]
0.1 01110111010010000000101001000001100011011100011111  0.052908822741908   2.7185508579738e-05
```

I guess it is a type casting problem. The first part has an string input and string database, so it works. However, the second part automatically reads input and data from files as integers. I searched the type casting and realized there is no casting function in Perl (Or I am wrong). Please let me know any idea and/or recommendation to resolve this issue.

In short, I wanted to make matching with dont care condition works with input and database files. Please let me know if you have other ways to work this. (I used a temporary value change in the input file)

Comment: Is your input actually binary, or is it ascii strings of 1s and 0s? (if you `cat` it do you get the above output?)

Comment: It is a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, type casting - that doesn't exist in the way you think, because perl doesn't really care whether something is a string or a number - it does the right thing depending on context.

However, there are things like `pack` and `unpack` which convert raw binary data to a more usable representation. E.g. from (raw) binary to hex, and back again. These don't seem to apply, because your input isn't binary - it's just text.

But I have to say - I think you're tackling this a harder way than you need to (unless I'm misunderstanding your problem) and you don't actually need to do binary transforming at all:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

#or read this from a file
my @input = qw ( 11XX11001000101101111101101010010000101101011111X1
                 1000011000111101001011110111001100100101111000010X );
#replace 'X' with '.' which is the regex "don't care" character.                 
s/X/./g for @input;
#compile a regex made of these two patterns. 
my $search = join ( "|", @input );
   $search = qr/$search/; 

print "Compiled input patterns into a regex of: \n";
print $search,"\n";

#iterate database (pasted in 'data' block for illustrative purposes)
while ( <DATA> ) {
    my ( $id, $target, @rest ) = split; #split on whitespace. 
              # you are using tab sep, so you might prefer split /\t/;
    #field 1 = ID
    #field 2 = $target
    #everything else = @rest
    #compare $target with the regex we compiled above, and print the 
    #current line if it matches. 
    print if $target =~ /$search/;
}


__DATA__
0.1 11001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101  rml_irf_old_e_cwp_e[1]  rml_irf_new_e_cwp_e[1]  rml_irf_swap_even_e rml_irf_old_e_cwp_e[0]  rml_irf_new_e_cwp_e[0]  rml_irf_swap_odd_e
0.1 11101100110010011011001101100111001001100000010011  3.923510310023e-06  3.19470818154393e-08    7.05437377900141e-10    7.05437377900141e-10    4.89200539851702e-17    5.01433479478681e-19
0.1 10000110001111010010111101110011001001011110000100  rml_irf_new_e_cwp_e[1]  rml_irf_new_e_cwp_e[0]
0.1 01110111010010000000101001000001100011011100011111  0.052908822741908   2.7185508579738e-05
```

This then, for your database, prints:

```
0.1 11001100100010110111110110101001000010110101111101  rml_irf_old_e_cwp_e[1]  rml_irf_new_e_cwp_e[1]  rml_irf_swap_even_e rml_irf_old_e_cwp_e[0]  rml_irf_new_e_cwp_e[0]  rml_irf_swap_odd_e
0.1 10000110001111010010111101110011001001011110000100  rml_irf_new_e_cwp_e[1]  rml_irf_new_e_cwp_e[0]
```

In terms of reading patterns from a particular file - the most likely reason that would break is if you forget to `chomp` the patterns as you read them.

So you'd load them like this (tested with the above data):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

#Read patterns from file
open ( my $input_fh, '<', 'patterns.txt' ) or die $!; 
chomp ( my @input = <$input_fh> );
close ( $input_fh );
#replace 'X' with '.' which is the regex "don't care" character.                 
s/X/./g for @input;
#compile a regex made of these two patterns. 
my $search = join ( "|", @input );
   $search = qr/$search/; 

#iterate database (pasted in 'data' block for illustrative purposes)
open ( my $data, '<', 'database.txt' ) or die $!;
while ( <$data> ) {
    my ( $id, $target, @rest ) = split;
    #print if the target line matches
    print if $target =~ /$search/;
}
```

Specifically with your code (and that of your answer):

- Turn on `use strict; use warnings;` - it's important for troubleshooting.
- You don't need to double-loop, because turning your input patterns into an alternation regex does that for you (more efficiently).
- Always use 3 arg open with lexical file handles. `open ( my $input_fh, '<', 'patterns.txt' ) or die $!` because a file handle of `CSV` is a global (and doesn't auto close like a lexical does when it goes out of scope).
- `$i < (scalar @Ddb)` is redundant. `<` makes it a scalar context, so you can can just `$i < @db` and get the same result.
- `perltidy` is a good thing for code formatting. `perltidy -pbp` will format based on "perl best practices".

Comment: Thank you. Either way is fine to me. I think "." is the symbol what I wanted to originally. I have modified my code, but it seems I did not understand the part in while loop correctly. Could you explain the details? I will attach my code in the following. Thank  you.

Comment: The problem you are having with reading is that you aren't `chomp` ing the input, so it has embedded linefeeds.

Comment: Also, you don't really want the open inside your `do` block. I suspect that means you will end up with the return code of `open` contaminating your list. Try `open my $input_fh, '<', 'file.txt' or die $! ; chomp ( my @input = <$input_fh> );`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help -  @Sobrique

My original code made my code more complicated. What I wanted to do is actually ".", which is a dont care symbol and the way to handle this symbol. Also, reading csv files as an input and database is needed. @sobrique helped me a lot to resolved all the issues and the following is my final code.

my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

##### Read input

open my $input_fh, '<', 'input_test.txt' or die $! ; chomp ( my @input = <$input_fh> );

#replace 'X' with '.' which is the regex "don't care" character.                 
s/X/./g for @input;
#compile a regex made of these two patterns. 
#my $search = join ( "|", @input ); 
#   $search = qr/$search/;      
my $search = join ( "|", $input[0] ); 
   $search = qr/$search/;   

##### Read database
open(CSV,'database.txt')||die("Cannot open db file $!");
my @Ddb;
while(<CSV>){
    my @row=split(/\t/,$_);
    push(@Ddb,\@row);
}
close CSV || die $!;


#iterate database (pasted in 'data' block for illustrative purposes)
for (my $n=0; $n < (scalar @input); $n +=2) {

for (my $i=0; $i < (scalar @Ddb); $i +=2) {
    if ($Ddb[$i][1] =~ /$search/) {
        print "$Ddb[$i][1] matched\n";
        print "$Ddb[$i][2] \n";
    } 
#else {
#       print "$Ddb[$i][1] didn't match\n";      
#       }
}

}
```

input_test.txt :

```
10001000110010001001110111000011001010110010000011
10111101010011000101001011110000001110101110010011
```

Comment: Needs a `chomp` to remove the line feed.

Comment: But this should really be an edit to your questions, because this is not really an answer.

Comment: Yes, I will update my answer. I have fixed the problem with the input based on you comment. thank you.

Comment: The scalar in the array size comparison is redundant. Comparison operators are scalar context already.

Comment: Also you are iterating @input when you don't need to because $search does the same thing.

Comment: I have edited my answer to clarify. Your code it still too convoluted. Compiling a regex based on `$input[0]` is not going to do what you want, because you're effectively discarding all but one of the patterns.

Comment: @Sorbique, Thank you for your comment. The reason I iterated input is that I wanted to search the case both lines are matched. For example, in my database, two lines are repeated. The first line contains names of registers and the second lines are numbers. So I exactly wanted to search is the case the two lines are matched with the input containing two lines. Is there any fancy way except for iterating input that I used? I wanted to ask the way to search one line for simplicity.